# How to make textbox to remembers the previous input in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How to make the textbox to remember the previous input in Excel VBA?

I found that I have to save input value to any other cells and load when the form is open. I dont know how to do it. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: "Please give me a simple code too." - Sorry, but SO isn't a "code for me" site, but rather "help me with my code."  What have you tried so far? This is a pretty common thing to do, I'd be surprised if there's no site/answer online. What have you searched for? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: Like @BruceWayne said, SO is not for asking for code. Please write a but of code and show it before asking for help.

Comment: guys, Stop hating the guy for not knowing the rules, maybe 'teach' him instead?

Comment: @Behrooz - No hate...We're not against teaching people, we're here to help! I suggest OP also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  There are myriad resources online that have what they're trying to do.  SO is a place to get specific help with specific problems, not a general "How do I do this, give me the code" site.  Also, in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), " Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out this is not a code site, thus plain old English.
First, You need a static variable to store the previous value, static because it should not vanish from memory after your 'current' event is over.
Then, You need to set said variable after an input is checked in your event to have it ready for the next time.
so, this is how it goes:

```
static varible here  

inside your event sub:  
checking the variable to see if this is the first run
use previous value from variable  
set current value from input to variable
```

If you need the variable to persist between runs you should store it in a cell instead of static variable.

P.S. I'm not doing this to hurt you or hate you or make a point; It's a simple reason, "This is how you can learn."